# adding connection string to model but on update it removes it

Tags: c#, model

I am adding these lines to my SuburbanPortalModel.Context.cs:

```
  public SuburbanPortalEntities(string nameOrConnectionString)
    : base(nameOrConnectionString)
  {
  }
```

When I update the Model, this is being wiped out.

Here it is in the class:

```
public partial class SuburbanPortalEntities : DbContext
{
    public SuburbanPortalEntities()
        : base("name=SuburbanPortalEntities")
    {
    }

    public SuburbanPortalEntities(string nameOrConnectionString)
      : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
```

Where do I need to put this so it is not wiped out on each update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your changes are being wiped out because `SuburbanPortalModel.Context.cs` is auto generated by the .tt file.

For renaming the connection string that EF is using, check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2281359/14515)

If you still wanted to persist your changes though, you would leverage the fact that the generated DbContext is a partial class.

So create a new `SuburbanPortalEntities` class (in a separate file of course) and put your changes there.

```
public partial class SuburbanPortalEntities : DbContext
{

    public SuburbanPortalEntities(string nameOrConnectionString)
      : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }

    //public void MyCustomDoFoo(){

    //}

}
```

Comment: perfect! tyvm for your help!